# Windows 8.1 Locks Screen on Screen Blackout Instead of On Sleep Like Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

On Windows 8, the computer "locked" (you have to log back in to use it) whenever it went to sleep or hibernated (or turned off or on, obviously), but did not lock when the screen turned off but the computer did not go to sleep. However, after the update to Windows 8.1, it seems the computer locks when the screen turns black, as well, and I can't figure out how to have it lock *only* when it sleeps or hibernates. This is slowing me down, as I would like the screen to turn off after a short time but not have to log back in every 20 minutes I don't use it.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this setting in the Power Options.  I was having a similar issue.  I noticed the setting when I went to check on the settings in Change Advanced Power Settings.

I am not in front of my Win8.1 machine right now so can't give you the exact setting to change.  I recall that it was obvious when I saw it.  Something like...require password after wake, or something very similar.

Good Luck if you haven't already solved this.

EDIT: Here is a screen shot of the power option for Win8.1.

[image: power options]

Comment: Come back any time and edit your answer when you have the exact details.

Comment: Couldn't find it. I did find a setting before that seemed to work sometimes but then stopped working altogether. It was in the new `PC Settings` app, but I forget which setting.

Comment: Yes, I saw that option, but, if you read my question, I still want it to lock after sleeping. I just don't want it to lock when the screen turns off but the computer does not go to sleep. I have edited my question to clarify.

Comment: Did you double check on the screen saver settings page?  The check box says "On resume, display logon screen"

Comment: Yes. That option is not checked. This has nothing to do with the screen saver anyway.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't have to do with screen saver.  It has to do with the screen going black, which MS classifies as a screen saver as well as power saver, which produces a lock screen.  Just because a setting is labelled a certain way, doesn't mean it doesn't have a dual use.  Try that setting I originally mentioned.  My PC doesn't utilize Sleep Mode, yet that setting removed the lock screen after my screens went dark.  Good Luck with your issue.